# Using 'Replace' Function in Python

Tags: python

I have an access table that has a bunch coordinate values in degrees minutes seconds and they are formatted like this:

90-12-28.15

I want to reformat it like this:

90° 12' 28.15"

essentially replacing the dashes with the degrees minutes and seconds characters and a space between the degrees and minutes and another one between the minutes and seconds.

I'm thinking about using the 'Replace' function, but I'm not sure how to replace the first instance of the dash with a degree character (°) and space and then detect the second instance of the dash and place the minute characters and a space and then finally adding the seconds character at the end.

Any help is appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 5):

While regular expressions and `split()` are fine solutions, doing this with `replace()` is rather easy.

```
lat = "90-12-28.15"

lat = lat.replace("-", "° ", 1)
lat = lat.replace("-", "' ", 1)
lat = lat + '"'
```

Or you can do it all on one line:

```
lat = lat.replace("-", "° ", 1).replace("-", "' ", 1) + '"'
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

I would just split your first string:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str = '90-12-28.15'

arr = str.split('-')   
str2 = arr[0] +'° ' + arr[1] + '\'' +arr[2] +'"'

print str2
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Python's regular expressions module `re`, particularly `re.sub()`. Check the Python docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more information.

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, check out this tutorial [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/regex.html), also from the Python documentation.

```
import re

text = 'replace "-" in 90-12-28.15'
print(re.sub(r'(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)\.(\d\d)', r'''\1° \2' \3.\4"''', text))
# use \d{1,2} instead of \d\d if single digits are allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

The python "replace" string method should be easy to use. You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace).

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
my_str = "90-12-28.15"
my_str = my_str.replace("-","°",1)# 1 means you are going to replace the first ocurrence only
my_str = my_str.replace("-","'",1)
my_str = my_str + "\""
```

Comment: The link you provided has no information on the replace method that I could find. The actual information is in the link on that page at the top `String Methods` which takes you [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).